# Making Photos use more memory when it is running in the background for People Tagging tasks

Tags: macos, photos, memory, photos.app

Is there a way to make the Photos app perform more computations when it is running in the background?

Basically, I read that People Tagging happens when the computer is plugged and when Photos is not open. Which means that I could easily leave my computer switched on for the night to allow Photos to do its Machine Learning stuff.
But when I look at the Terminal, the PhotoAgent, photoanalysisd etc. are only using very small amount of my computer's resources.

**Isn't there a way to speed things up?** For example, by allocating more memory to Photos, etc.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but I guess you guys are really picky on this AskDifferent forum, as compared to SOF.